# How to handle properly firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I can not find how should handle the auth part correctly. Basically, my backend returns me a token, and with this token, I call auth().signInWithCustomToken(token). All works fine my users have access to chat and other things. Also, on signout I call auth.signout(). But the problem is if the user does not use the app for some time and when coming to the app with refresh token if it is valid we generate new accessToken. But how to handle firebase part in this flow because user can not access chat, etc because it seems firebase token is not valid anymore. Any idea how to handle refresh token or flow in this case?

Comment: Did you ever got this to work Jalson1982? In my app I open the app using a fake page that only shows an activity spinner. While this is spinning the token & validity time is checked. If this is expired a new token is requested using the refreshtoken, if that doesn't succeed the new token is requested. 
However even with the new token users are unable to use the Firebase database because they are not signed in. So I guess it is the same problem as you were having?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've signed out with `signout()`, refreshing a token won't help at all.  The user is fully and completely signed out.  If you want to sign back in, you will need another new token to sign in with `signInWithCustomToken()`.  Once the user *is* signed in, the Firebase SDK will automatically refresh a token to keep that sign-in alive for a long as needed.  There is nothing you need to do for that.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, Doug. We have faced a strange issue. We had version 5 of firebase in our react native app and then we update it to version 9. All is fine. But some users that did not use the app for a month or similar after the update can not use some resources because the firebase token for sure is not ok. Most of the users are ok but still, we did not understand do we need to handle anything when user come back to the app, we generate new access token based on refresh token but it seems firebase token is not valid anymore and users can not access chats, etc.